# Is it possible to use TOP N WITH TIES with Union?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to find the housekeeper and the guide with the most tasks in their respective tables, and I am trying to do this with union to show in one result, but I'm getting this error:

"The TOP N WITH TIES clause is not allowed without a corresponding ORDER BY clause."

```
SELECT TOP 1 with ties e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ScheduleID) as 'Task Count'
FROM EMPLOYEE e, CLEANING c
where e.empid = c.hkid
group by e.empid
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 with ties e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ResID) as 'Task Count'
FROM EMPLOYEE e, RESERVATION r
where e.empid = r.guideid
group by e.empid
order by 'Task Count' desc
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TOP is a product specific functionality.)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Another tip: Don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 with ties e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ScheduleID) as 'Task Count'
    FROM EMPLOYEE e, CLEANING c
    where e.empid = c.hkid
    group by e.empid
    order by [Task Count] desc
)  DS
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 with ties e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ResID) as 'Task Count'
    FROM EMPLOYEE e, RESERVATION r
    where e.empid = r.guideid
    group by e.empid
    order by [Task Count] desc
) DS
```

or this one:

```
SELECT SELECT TOP 1 with ties EmployeeID, [Task Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ScheduleID) as 'Task Count'
    FROM EMPLOYEE e, CLEANING c
    where e.empid = c.hkid
    group by e.empid
    UNION
    SELECT ties e.EmpID as 'EmployeeID', Count(ResID) as 'Task Count'
    FROM EMPLOYEE e, RESERVATION r
    where e.empid = r.guideid
    group by e.empid
    
) DS
order by [Task Count] desc
```

Comment: `order by 'Task Count' desc` is somewhat pointless, as it doesn't apply any order; `'Task Count'` in the `ORDER BY` doesn't reference the column aliased with a single string alias, it just orders the data by the *literal string* `'Task Count'`, which as that will be the same value for *every* row will mean that the ordering is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the comments, the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax should really be replaced. The ANSI-92 Syntax has been around for over *30* years.